# How to serve all dependencies for Google Charts from the local server itself

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

**Scenario:** We are developing a web application, which basically works locally on LAN. It consists of report module which in-turn includes chart report. I had developed a prototype for pie, bar, column and many different chart on the actual data.

**Issue:** The [Google Charts](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) does not work offline, I tried to dump the dependencies on local server but not able to figure out all the dependencies.

**Question:**  Can anyone tell me how to make it work? i.e. how to serve all dependencies for  [Google Charts](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery) from the local server itself.

Advance Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer: you [can't](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq#localdownload) host google chart on your own server.

You might want to take a look at libraries like [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/products/highcharts) and [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/)